# Why does not HashSet.add(Object) replace existing object?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset

This is more of a design question in which I am curious as to why the HashSet does not support put like operation with the add.

If I want to update an object with equal hashCode as an existing object I have to do this:

```
hashSet.remove(o);
hasSet.add(o);
```

I think a

```
hashSet.add(o);
```

should have sufficed since it uses a HashMap under the hood anyway.

Comment: Your problem is that your understand of the semantics of HashSets is not correct. In other words: first try to understand the API before making guesses how to improve it ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat My question remains a question. And at that, a question that starts with a Why. So Im looking to learn.

Comment: Sure. I am just pointing out: in your case, prior research would have been pretty easy; like reading the corresponding javadocs.

Comment: JavaDocs is the great dictator that explains the Semantics but not the "Why". @Erans sheds some light. I clearly know how to use the API as demonstrated in my question.

Comment: Indeed (Hand on face). :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no point to replace a `HashSet` element with an element equal to it. In `HashMap` there is a point to replace the entry for an existing key, since the value can be different.

> I think a `hashSet.add(o);` should have sufficed since it uses a `HashMap` under the hood anyway.

Actually no. You are correct that `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, where each element of the `Set` is a key and the value is a dummy object. However, since `map.put(key,value)` doesn't replace the key if an equal key is present in the `Map` (it only replaces the value), `HashSet` cannot replace the element if it already exists in the `Set` without first removing it.

Comment: I see. The hashCode of my Class is based only on a single field which is the id field similar to a row id in the db.

Comment: That's the catch, there is no value but a dummy one.

Comment: @F.O.O Also note that it is not (only) the `hashCode` that is important here, it is the `equals`: ["More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-). There can be multiple values with colliding hashCodes in a `HashSet`, lookup is just less efficient then.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a `Set` is to keep track of unique elements added to it. But "unique" here means "not equal to anything else in the set", as defined by your `.equals()` method.

If you have a case where you need to add two things that are equal, it suggests that either you don't really want a `Set` at all, or your `.equals()` method isn't quite right. The point of `.equals()` is that if you've got it right, you won't really care which of `a` and `b` are in the set if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

The Set [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) clearly specify this behaviour.

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation)(...)